# Adding a 3rd sub menu

Tags: html, css

I like to add a third sub menu there is only 2 sub menus . . .but i am bit confused . . .please help me with it guys. .
My html and css code are in the link below in JS fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xZKE8/

What I Have now is

Ex: ProductA > Product 1 >Sub product 1

What I need is

Ex: ProductA > Product 1 >Sub product 1 >Sub product 1_1

```
<div id="menuwrapper">
<ul>
 <li><a href="#" Title="Products A" >Products A</a>
<ul>
 <li><a href="#" Title="Product 1">Product 1</a>
<ul>
 <li><a href="#" Title="Sub Product 1">Sub Product 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" Title="Sub Product 2">Sub Product 2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" Title="Sub Product 3">Sub Product 3</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" Title="Sub Product 4">Sub Product 4</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" Title="Sub Product 5">Sub Product 5</a></li>
</ul>   
 </li>
</ul>   
 </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another `ul` inside the `<li><a href="#" Title="Sub Product 1">Sub Product 1</a></li>` and add as many `li` as you want then style it with `id` `#menuwrapper ul ul ul ul` or you can style like this `#menuwrapper ul:nth-child(3)` and I think it will work. If can't then tell.

I have updated your fiddle. Please check it: http://jsfiddle.net/xZKE8/4/ . I have added just two line CSS with yours'.

```
#menuwrapper ul li ul li ul li ul li{display:none;}
#menuwrapper ul li ul li ul li:hover > ul li{display:block !important;}
```

Comment: Ya Joy. . .the prob is with my styling. . .can u edit the fiddle and show me

Answer (score 1):

As Joy_S stated, you just nest as many `<ul>`'s as you need.

As for the CSS, the original code goes about showing the hidden sub levels in an inefficient way.  Rather that using `#menuwrapper ul li ul li ul li ul ...` blah blah blah for every single submenu, just use one selector for every li to unhide ONLY is direct child ul using `>`.

```
 #menuwrapper ul li:hover > ul, 
 #menuwrapper ul li.iehover > ul{
     left:175px;
     top:0px;
     display:block;
 }
```

This one block will work on every menu item for any number of submenus.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xZKE8/2/)

I go rid of all the superfluous CSS to show what is unnecessary to make this type of menu function.